# Stack Overflow search engine for browsers

Tags: support, search, search-engine

I would like to use Stack Overflow as a search engine in my browsers.

> [image]

Most of the time when I have a programming problem, I would like to search only on Stack Overflow, or Stack Exchange sites. So, I need to bookmark Stack Exchange sites, go there and type in my search query.

I would like to skip all these steps and enter my search terms directly in my browser's search bar. Is this possible (maybe with a plugin)? If not, could this feature be added?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We already insert OpenSearch metadata in every page. Since your screenshot looks like Firefox, and Firefox supports OpenSearch by default, all you have to do is go to http://stackoverflow.com, and then open the very popup that's in your screenshot – it will display the option *Add "Stack Overflow"*.

Answer (score 7):

The query string for **Stack Overflow** is https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s

**How to set it:**

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Go to chrome://settings/searchEngines
3. On "Site search" section click "Add" button
4. Fill the form like on the picture with URL=https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s and click "Add"
5. Use "so something" in Address bar to search for "something" on Stack Overflow

[image: Add search engine]

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard for example, it is possible to [add this link to Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426#url) as search engine address.

Comment: In Firefox, just bookmarking the URL (`https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s`) and assigning the shortcut "so" for it in field *"Keyword"* (in menu *"Boomarks"* → *"Manage Boomarks"*) works. (The bookmark does not have to be visible in the *Bookmarks* menu and can be placed in "Other Bookmarks".)